# Converting width of website

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website that is 960px wide. It is mainly geared towards a 'creative' audience, and contains a lot of video. I would like to convert the site to be 1000px wide, and was wondering if there would be any downsides of doing so? If so, what are they specifically?

Comment: Can you give your website URL.

Comment: You know you can use relative values? You could do for example: `width: 100%;`. So, if you use procentual values always, you don't need to convert anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this site: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7932/what-is-the-standard-width-for-a-website-in-pixels

It could be use to you. and this tells elaborate of your question.